# Setting a delay for an action on ListBox _SelectedIndexChanged

Tags: c#, listbox, delay

I have a listbox with filenames.  When the selected index is changed I load the file.

I want something like jQuery's HoverIntent that delays the action of loading the file for a short time so the user can use the down arrow and quickly cycle through the items in the list without the application trying to load each one.  Thread.Sleep pauses the whole app so a user can't select another list item until the sleep completes, this is obviously not what I want.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work if your using `WinForms`, make a call to the `InitTimer` method in the `Form` constructor.

Load the file in the `_timer_Tick` event handler. To change the delay set the `Interval` property in `InitTimer` to another value.

```
private System.Windows.Forms.Timer _timer;

private void InitTimer()
{
    _timer = new Timer { Interval = 500 };
    _timer.Tick += _timer_Tick;
}

private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _timer.Stop();
    _timer.Start();
}

private void _timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _timer.Stop();
    // TODO: Load file here
}
```

Comment: Great!! Works like a beast! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Winforms:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private CancellationTokenSource _cancel;
    private object _loadLock = new object();

    private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lock (_loadLock)
        {

            handleCancellation();

            var loader = new Task((chosenFileItemInListbox) =>
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    LoadFile(chosenFileItemInListbox);
                }, listBox1.SelectedItem, _cancel.Token);
        }
    }

    private bool handleCancellation()
    {
        bool cancelled = false;

        lock (_loadLock)
        {
            if (_cancel != null)
            {
                if (!_cancel.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    _cancel.Cancel();
                    cancelled = true;
                }
                _cancel = null;
            } 
        }

        return cancelled;
    }

    private void LoadFile(object chosenFileItemInListbox)
    {
        if (handleCancellation())
        {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

The code above could also be applied to WPF, but WPF contains some built in magic for handling delays and cancellation of previous updates.

```
<ListBox SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedFile, Delay=1000}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Threading to separate the loading from your GUI.

This should get you started:

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

```
CancellationTokenSource cts;
bool loading;

private void SelectedIndexChanged(int index)
{
    if (loading)
        cts.Cancel();

    cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

    var loader = new Task.Delay(1000);
    loader.ContinueWith(() => LoadFile(index))
          .ContinueWith((x) => DisplayResult(x));

    loader.Start();
}

private void DisplayResult(Task t)
{
    // TODO: Invoke this Method to MainThread
    if (!cts.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        // Actually display this file
    }
}
```

Could not test, as I'm still on .net 4 whereas Task.Delay() is .net 4.5
You may need to add another field in the form for the file content transfer from the tasks to the GUI.